# Replace work in line by combining after grep

Tags: awk, sed, grep, cat

I need to replace a word after performing a grep and getting the last line of the result.

Here my example file:

```
aaa ts1 ts2
bbb ts3 ts4
aaa ts5 ts6
aaa ts7 NONE
```

What I need is to select all lines containing 'aaa', get the last one in the result and replace NONE.

I tried

```
cat <file> | grep "aaa" | tail -n 1 | sed -i 's/NONE/ts8/g'
```

but it doesn't work.

Any suggestion to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `tac` + `awk` solution please try following.

```
tac Input_file | awk '/aaa/ && ++count==1{sub(/NONE/,"ts8")} 1' | tac
```

once you are happy with above command try following, to do inplace save into Input_file.

```
tac Input_file | awk '/aaa/ && ++count==1{sub(/NONE/,"ts8")} 1' | tac > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Firstly printing Input_file in reverse order by `tac` then sending its standard output to `awk` as an input where substituting  of NONE to ts8 in very first line(which is actually last line containing `aaa`). Simply printing all other lines, again sending output to `tac` to make it in actual order like Input_file's order.

Answer (score 2):

For doing this in a single command, this should work in any version of `awk`:

```sh
awk 'FNR==NR {if ($1=="aaa") n=FNR; next} FNR == n {$3="TS7"} 1' file{,}

aaa ts1 ts2
bbb ts3 ts4
aaa ts5 ts6
aaa ts7 TS7
```

To save output in same file use:

```sh
awk 'FNR==NR {if ($1=="aaa") n=FNR; next}
FNR == n {$3="TS7"} 1' file{,} > file.out && mv file.out file
```

Or using `gnu sed`, you may use:

```sh
sed -i -Ez 's/(.*\naaa[[:blank:]]+[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+)NONE/\1ts8/' file

cat file

aaa ts1 ts2
bbb ts3 ts4
aaa ts5 ts6
aaa ts7 ts8
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the last line that matches aaa at the start, you can go through all lines, and in the END block, print the last occurrence and replace `NONE` with `ts8` using awk:

```
awk '$1=="aaa"{last=$0}END{sub(/NONE/,"ts8",last);print last}' file
```

In parts:

```
$1=="aaa" {               # If the first field is aaa
  last=$0                 # Set variable last to the whole line (overwrite on each match)
}
END {                     # Run once at the end                
  sub(/NONE/,"ts8",last)  # Replace NONE with ts8 in the last variable
  print last                 
}
' file
```

Output

```
aaa ts7 ts8
```